# For-loop through 2 vectors and create new relative vector

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 2 vectors, (`x` and `y`), which are coordinate points for a grid. I have a few lines of code to take each point (`x[i]` and `y[i]`) and return a value for the point. I want that returned value to be placed in a new list ('v').

Here's what I'm thinking:

```
v = c()
for(i in x & y){
  getval(x[i], y[i]) # placeholder/theoretical function
  v[i] = ptval # ptval returned from getval()
}
```

This isn't working, though, and I think it has to do with a formatting issue in the `for`-loop.

Here's an example of what I want for the final data, where `x` and `y` are inputs (gps coordinates, in reality) and v is the return from `getval()`:

```
x    y    v
1    1    0
1    2    0
1    3    1
2    1    0
2    2    0
2    3    2
3    1    3
3    2    1
3    3    0
```

Comment: `for ( i in 1 : length(x)){#your calculation here}`

Comment: @Wen What about the y vector? I need to plug both x[i] AND y[i] into my caluclations

Comment: I posted, if it did not work let me know

Comment: I think this worked, thank you!

Comment: How about `mapply(getval, x, y)`?

Comment: Then you can try to accept my answer

Comment: @Wen Then you can try to up-vote my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v = c()
for(i in 1:length(x){
  getval(x[i], y[i]) # placeholder/theoretical function
  v[i] = ptval # ptval returned from getval()
}
```

or if you need all combination from x and y

```
expand.grid(x,y)
```